# Best isolation level for a conditional insert based on a select

Tags: database, postgresql, isolation-level

I have a simple table `offer_proposals` that stores the history of offers proposed to a user:

| id | user_id | proposed_on |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'aaa' | 2022-01-31 20:10:25-07 |
| 2 | 'aaa' | 2022-01-01 20:10:25-07 |
| 3 | 'bbb' | 2022-01-31 20:10:25-07 |

And a SERIALIZABLE transaction that driven by a web request taht returns true/false depending on whether it finds a record in the last 30 days, specifically:

1. Selects the latest record for a given user ID (`select proposed_on from offer_proposals where user_id = 'aaa' order by proposed_on limit 1`)
2. If the record is older than 30 days (or doesn't exist) return true and insert a new record for that user ID with the current timestamp (`insert into offer_proposals (user_id, proposed_on) values('aaa', '~now()')` otherwise return false

This works but lock acquisition exceptions / rollbacks are becoming an issue. Without changing the table design, is there a better way (different isolation level, locks, etc) to implement this transaction that is more performant? It seems like `read_commited` may work but I'm unclear if I'd need additional locking.

explain(analyze, buffers) shows:

```
Buffers: shared hit=6
-> Sort (cost 8.3..8.31 rows=1 width=48) (actual time=0.195..0.196 rows=1 loops=1)
  Sort key proposed_on
  Sort method: quicksort memory: 25kB
  Buffers shared hit=6
  -> Index Scan using offer_proposal_user_id_idx on offer_proposal (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=48) (actual time=0.182..0.183 rows=1 loops=1)
     Index Cond (user_id=1234)
     Buffers shared hit=3
Planning time 0.816 ms
Execution time  0.238 ms
```

Comment: Performance probably has more to do with indexes than with isolation level.  Is the slow part the select, the insert, or the commit?  What does EPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) of the select show?

Comment: Sorry I say performance but what I actually meant was I was getting lock acquisition exceptions / transaction rollbacks.

Comment: I don't know what "lock acquisition exceptions" are, but serialization errors are expected in this situation.  The usual way to deal with them is to catch them and retry.

Comment: Ya that's what I'm doing now, but as I understand a `serializable` isolation level essentially locks the entire table, which is overkill. I'm looking for something more like a "range lock" (ie I'd like to lock only rows associated with the given user_id) which would allow me to lower the isolation level and hopefully improve performance.

Comment: It will automatically use a range lock if one is available for the plan.  So I think we are back to wondering what indexes you have and what `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` shows.

Comment: Good to know - I have just two indexes, the a unique index for the primary key, and a regular index (btree) for the user_id column. I've edited the question to include the execution plan, which seems fine to me? I suppose I could add an ordered index w/ proposed on?

Comment: If you change isolation level to read committed, you will probably get some duplicate inserts.  But you will probably also find the performance does not actually get better by a significant amount, which if so means there is no point in trying to make it be correct under read committed, as it won't be faster anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is users table with user_id column, it can be dobe in one insert

```sql
insert into offer_proposals (user_id, proposed_on)
select user_id, current_date from users 
  where not exists 
   (select * from offer_proposals 
     where user_id = users.user_id 
       and proposed_on >= current_date - INTERVAL '30 days');
```

insert into offer_proposals (user_id, proposed_on)
select user_id,

Comment: This is an interesting solution but I'm not sure it'd work - there isn't a users table rather the user_id comes from a webrequest and the service returns whether or not they have already been served an offer in the last 30 days (ie the result of step #1)